# Unable to add application server in IntelliJ Community Edition with Gradle

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, gradle

I am trying to build web services using spring mvc framework. I am using IntelliJ Community Edition IDE and gradle build system.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.1.3-2'
        springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:${kotlinVersion}")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

}
```

Application build successfully. But I couldn't find option to add application server (Tomcat) in Community Edition with Gradle.

```
Welcome to Gradle 3.5.1.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.817 secs

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Does anyone know how to add tomcat application server in IntelliJ Community Edition with Gradle system ?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know this feature is only available in the Ultimate Edition.

Comment: @C-Otto Yep, there is inbuilt option in Ultimate Edition but there should be work around to add it and get this done.

Comment: Sure, just pay for the feature :)

Comment: There is work around for maven https://dzone.com/articles/headless-setup-java-project but couldn't find for gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin to add tomcat with `Gradle` in Community Edition.

Add this plugin in the buildscript dependencies

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        .....
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.3'
    }
}
```

Apply this plugin `apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'`

Now you need to add tomcat runtime libraries to the tomcat configurations. I had this that may work for you.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    ....
    def tomcatVersion = '8.0.42'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
}
```

Hope this helps to you.

Answer (score 2):

as per my knowledge it is not available in Community Edition.
It is available in Ultimate Edition only.

Please refer this link:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: Nope. you can do this, hope my answer can help you!